# Plasma button or command to show desktop grid

Tags: kde, command, plasma, kde-activities

[image]

I find useful the desktop grid to drag & drop windows of applications between virtual desktops and I know that it can be displayed with a shortcut.

[image]

But sometimes I do it more often and when I am using a mouse so I am curious whether we can do it by clicking a button (or by a command that I can put in a launcher) in the way I do for activities

[image]

... or the way we can do (I realized it in the end!... but I don't do it) - with the pager widget, which allows dragging windows between the small buttons on the panel (too small for this purpose, too large to have them on the panel all the time as far as I concerned):

[image]

Also, I know an alternative is hot corners - but I still want a button (I always bump into hot corners by error- sorry that I'm so picky!)

[Plasma 4 had an extension/widget](https://store.kde.org/p/1001839/) for that purpose but I cannot find one for Plasma 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to find an answer I have found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/mn0h9g/how_do_i_make_meta_key_the_shortcut_for_showing/), and from the commands posted there (also by trial and error) I came up with the good command:

```
qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/kwin invokeShortcut ShowDesktopGrid
```

I have added that to a desktop "link to application", thus creating a `.desktop` file launcher which can be dragged onto the panel.

[image]